# Show/hide text with button

Tags: android, textview, android-button

I am trying to show text with a `button` click.

Here is my `onClick` code:

```
public class Uteliv extends Activity {

    public void onCrate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_uteliv);

        TextView tidiTekst = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tidiTekst);
        tidiTekst.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        Button tidiKnapp= (Button) findViewById(R.id.tidiKnapp);
        tidiKnapp.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            tidiTekst.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        }
     });
   }
}
```

What is wrong? When I test it on my phone I only get a blank page.

Comment: you are making your textview invisible isn't it working ? What exception do you get ?

Comment: what error are you getting? any?

Comment: Have you written `onCreate` only right? Cause in here it's written `onCrate`. .  AFAIK it should get compiled errors. But as you are saying it's running then it may be. Still double check it out.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Unless this was a typo in your post, your problem is you haven't declared the proper `Activity` method

```
public void onCrate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
```

should be

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
```

Also, you should probably make your `View`s member variables (declare them before `onCreate()` and initialize them inside of `onCreate()`)

**Edit**

To show/hide your `TextView` you can use [getVisibility](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#getVisibility%28%29) to determine what to do. So it would be something like

```
public void onClick(View v) {
        tidiTekst.setVisibility((tidiTekst.getVisibility() == View.Visible) 
                                                ? View.GONE : View.VISIBLE);
    }
```

Comment: Thats it! Thank for noticing :) How can I get it to close when text is shown?

Comment: What do you mean? What is the "it" that you want to close?

Comment: I don't understand. You want to hide the text when the text is shown? Right now you are setting the `TextView` to `Gone` then setting it to `VISIBLE` when the `Button` is clicked. What do you want to happen? When do you want to hide the text again?

Comment: First I click the button to show the text, then I want to click it one more time to hide the text

Answer (score 1):

activity_Main.xml

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="10dip" >



    <Button
        android:id="@+id/mybtn"
        style="?buttonBarButtonStyle"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#c4c5c7"
        android:shadowColor="#959597"
        android:shadowDx="0"
        android:shadowDy="1"
        android:shadowRadius="1"
        android:text="Button"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
    android:id="@+id/myTextView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
    android:text="hidden"
    android:visibility="gone"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

code for MainActivity.java

```
private TextView mytxtvw;
private Button myButton;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    mytxtvw=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.myTextView);
    myButton=(Button)findViewById(R.id.mybtn);

    onBtnClick();
}

public void onBtnClick()
{
    myButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            mytxtvw.setVisibility((mytxtvw.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) 
                    ? View.GONE : View.VISIBLE);

        }
    });



}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Define your button and textView variables outside of the on-create method. Until you post the error you are getting, I'm going to assume that you are getting a null pointer because they are going out of scope once onCreate is finished.

```
TextView tidiTekst;
Button tidiKnapp;

public void onCrate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_uteliv);


    tidiTekst = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tidiTekst);
    tidiTekst.setVisibility(View.GONE);

    tidiKnapp= (Button) findViewById(R.id.tidiKnapp);
    tidiKnapp.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            tidiTekst.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Still blank page when testing.

Answer (score 0):

Is it working if you decalre your textView as final ?

```
final TextView tidiTekst = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tidiTekst);
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check your **R.layout.activity_uteliv** in a WYSIWYG IDE such as Eclipse or IntelliJ IDEA, edit it in graphic mode, it must be something wrong with the layout(xml).

Answer (score 0):

In xml :

```
 <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_6sdp">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="MORE"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textColor="@color/darkgray"
                android:textSize="@dimen/_10sdp"
                android:gravity="left"
                android:id="@+id/moreone"/>
        </LinearLayout>
        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:background="@color/darkgray"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_6sdp"/>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_9sdp">
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="16) I will not indulge in any way in any act that is against the spirit of law and society. "
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textColor="@color/darkgray"
                android:textSize="@dimen/_10sdp"
                android:gravity="left"
                android:id="@+id/tandcone"/>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_6sdp">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="17) I will treat all with dignity irrespective and provide them with high level of service and remedies for their dissatisfaction any time during the course of my business as an Independent Associate."
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textColor="@color/darkgray"
                android:textSize="@dimen/_10sdp"
                android:gravity="left"
                android:id="@+id/tandctwo"/>
        </LinearLayout>
```

In MainActivity :

```
  moreone.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            tandcone.setVisibility((tandcone.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE)
                    ? View.GONE : View.VISIBLE);
            tandctwo.setVisibility((tandctwo.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE)
                    ? View.GONE : View.VISIBLE);

        }
    });
```